# Make multiple images cover entire viewport like css repeat

Tags: html, css, viewport

The easiest way to describe this is to refer to my fiddle here:

edit: had the wrong fiddle link, this is right though:

http://jsfiddle.net/b3rgstrom/k7qq4/2/

Here is my CSS:

```
.dynamic {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.dynamic img{
  margin: -2px;
}

.repeat {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I want to have a dynamic list of small images to cover the viewport within a fixed height area that covers the entire browser window from side to side.
The problem is that the images don't show up until they have their fully needed space, which in my example is 100px.

If I take one image and do a repeat, it will show as much of the image as needed to cover the entire screen from side to side, this is what I want to accomplish.

Let me know if I can clarify.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So are you trying to have multiple 100x100 images tile to fill the width of the screen? Or are you trying to have one background image tile to fill the width of the screen?

Comment: I'm trying to have multiple images cover the entire screen from left to right and to keep covering on resize.

Comment: It seems like you're going to have to explore a script solution, as css doesn't have the functionality to determine the viewport remaining and fill with objects. Are you open to this?

Comment: Sure, anything goes, it would be neat to solve it with CSS but I can understand if I have to explore other ways.

Comment: @b3rgstrom: Quick note... If you add a user name to a comment, like I did for this one with your name, the user will be alerted that someone replied to them. Otherwise, they might not see the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Oversized wrapper

Add a wrapper inside `.dynamic` with twice the width. That way the images are in an element that has more than enough width. The `overflow:hidden` on `.dynamic` prevents the extra width from triggering horizontal scrollbars.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CNJ7b/)

**CSS**

```
.dynamic {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamic .wrapper {
    width: 200%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dynamic">
    <div class="wrapper">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir, have earned a gold medal in my book. Works like a charm.

Comment: exactly what i was thinking, i just wasn't sure if this was what he actually wanted to do. +1 to you :)

Comment: @kristinachilds: Thanks! Sorry for independently stealing it from you ;) I pointed out to b3rgstrom about adding someone's name to a comment. You might have seen his clarification sooner if he had added your name.

Comment: Oh, I don't care. He got the help and that's what matters! I was distracted by my actual job for a few hours. Pft. How dare it!

Comment: @kristinachilds sorry if I forgot to mention you, thought the fiddle showed my intentions, next time huh?